# Internet not working with incorrect static network settings

Tags: internet

I have Ubuntu 14.4 LTS, 64 bits OS.

Since a restart today morning, my system is making problems.

My Skype on Ubuntu is working but i'm unable to ping google.com and even my Google Chrome browser is not accessing any website.

Even with any other browser, I'm unable to surf websites, even if Skype working well.
Teamviewer is not working too.

How to fix it ?

Comment: [resolved]


I had changed networking management ethernet connection.

IPv4 instead of automatic DHCP, I had changed Automatic(DHCP) Addresses only... So all issues comes,

I had reverted changes to Automatic(DHCP).

Now all works fine.



[Unable to put answer so commented here...]

Comment: Please even if you find the solution to your problem yourself after posting the question, post the solution as an answer to your own post and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[resolved]

I had changed networking management ethernet connection. IPv4 instead of automatic DHCP, I had changed Automatic(DHCP) Addresses only... So all issues comes, I had reverted changes to Automatic(DHCP). Now all works fine.

[Unable to put answer so commented here...]